# JavaScript Undefined issue from a JSON string

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to add data from a JSON string to a table in the following way:

```
tr = "<tr><td>" + data[i]["code"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["codeDesc"] + "</td></tr>";
```

But on execution I get:

`undefined<tr><td>C1713</td><td>ANCHOR/SCREW OPPOSING BN-TO-BN/SOFT TISSUE-TO-BN</td>`

I don't understand why this 'undefined' is getting appended.

Comment: It is likely that `["code"]` isn't a valid index of `[data][i]`. Can you please post your `data` array, along with your loop?

Comment: looks like your key names are wrong or are not long-enough paths, like you're missing a sub-property. Post the data if you want to know for sure.

Comment: Can you show the entire code where this falls under

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can guess what causes it but it could be from numerous things and there is not enough shown for anyone to reproduce problem

Comment: actually this is not a problem in browser its, but its casing problem in the 3rd party tool where I need to embidd it

Comment: That tells us next to nothing of value. Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]. Nobody can help when not enough information is given

Answer (score -1):

what you use jquery or pure javascript ?
if you use jquery  you should write something like

```
$("yourId").html(tr);
```

if you use pure javascript must be

`document.getElementById("yourId").innerHtml = tr;`

if you don't specificate this call undefined because the javascript don't know if this is only text or html tag .

Comment: This makes no sense at all and doesn't account for `undefined` being displayed in any way

Comment: you doesn't not understood what i say "undefined" is a error  how you pass your js to html this is the question if you use this method to pass the js  the word "undefined" disappear im sure